# Is there a way I can access authenticated user information in an API route in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a callback URL(mywebsite.com/final/results), which is a POST route, like:

```
Route::post('final/results','FinalResultsController@someMethod')
```

On this route, I am waiting for data that comes like

```
{"trx_id":"12","session":2,"method":"do","retry":true,"minus":20,"sign":"rthrtghert", "plus":0}
```

When the data comes, it is handled by the `someMethod` on `FinalResultsController` Now I need to get the logged-in information so that I can be able to update the user with the information. The problem is however that when I try to get the authenticated user through `auth('api')->user()`. it returns null. Is there any other way I can get the logged-in user information from the API route?

My project's Laravel version is 6.

Comment: this is API route ?

Comment: $request->user('api'); try this

Comment: do `Auth::user()` to get the information of the current logged in user

Answer (score 0):

instead of this use `Auth::user()` which will return current authenticated user data

in your `someMethod(){ $user=Auth::user(); }`

here is your `$user` you can do whatever you want with `$user`  or as you said update the information like

```
$user=User::find(Auth::id())
$user->name=$request->name;
$user->update();
```

Comment: "this" means what; reviewing your answer and too lazy to scroll through question to figure out. Please be complete. End of Review from within the "low Quality Answer" section ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get user object using

Auth()::user()